# Problem with getting variable from try catch blocks in Java

Tags: java, object, try-catch

I've got a strange problem with my program. I wrote the following code:

```
class Divide{

    int a, b;

        int divide(int a, int b) {

            try {

             if (b > 1)
                    throw new ArithmeticException("Generating exception");}
             catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                System.out.println("Caught exception 1st time" + e);

             throw e;

            }
        int c = a / b;


        return c; 
    } 
}
```

And after that I wanted to do exception handling
 and get variable from it in following way:

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Divide d = new Divide();

    int result = 0;

                    try
                    {
                        result = d.divide(12, 2);

                    } catch (ArithmeticException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("2 raz");
                    }

                    System.out.println(result); ///getting 0 insted of 6!

    }

}
```

And i am still getting varible before try-catch block. How can I do this type of exception handling and get the varible with value after use of divade method.

Comment: Semi-unrelated, but a and b do not need to be declared in the Divide class as they are initialized when the divide method is created with those two variables as parameters.

Comment: Why were you expecting `6`? You pass in a value of `2` for parameter `b`, so `b > 1` is true and it throws exception, which means that code prints `Caught exception 1st time: ArithmeticException: Generating exception` and `2 raz`, which means that `c = a / b` was never executed and `result` was never assigned from return value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you throw an exception whenever b is larger than 0, an exception is thrown when you run it with a value of 2. Thus, result is never updated, and 0 is displayed at the end of your program.

To obtain the correct output you will need to change your if statement in the divide method to not throw an exception any time b is greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `catch` with `throw e;` you rethrow an already caught error. 
This is why this

```
int c = a / b;
```

is not executed. 
If you remove

```
throw e;
```

you will get 6 as a result.